# SVG transform rotate

Tags: svg, rotation, transform

I'm wondering if anyone could tell me what the numbers inside rotate() stands for? I know the first one is the angle, but the other two?

`<line x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="20" transform="rotate(20 100 100)"></line>`

Answer (score 1):

1. The first number specifies a rotation in degrees.
2. The second number is the x coordinate of point (x, y) that the SVG rotates about.
3. The third number is the y coordinate of point (x, y) that the SVG rotates about.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Comment: Rather than saying "x-origin" and "y-origin", it might be clearer to say they are the X and Y coordinates of the centre of rotation (ie. around which the rotation should happen).

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one number within the rotate eg.: transform="rotate(10)" then the rotation happens around point (0,0)